# How can I use xproj (asp.net/dotnet core project) with shproj (shared project)?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, .net-core

Is it possible to reference a Shared project (.shrpoj) from a .Net core project (.xproj)?

I can't see a way, but I could be missing something.

#### Update

In case the link below stops working:

The alternative to shproj in .net core world is to add a `compile` section to the `buildOptions` section of the `project.json` file.

For example:

```
"buildOptions": {
 "compile": {
   "include": [
     "../../shared/**/*.cs"
   ]
 }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not supported. Sorry. You can share the code though by including the code files in `project.json`

#### Update

Here's how you include extra source files in a project: https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/blob/c83fbdbf127b95d8505b6a55010eb129f23e6530/src/MusicStore/project.json#L7-L12

Comment: oh ok; do you know if there are any plans to add support in the future? if you include an example of how to add a reference, I'll be happy to mark as answer :) (are you a MSFT employee?)

Comment: Updated the question with an example

Comment: ah yes, I'd seen that before somewhere! but obviously forgot! I take it that means they won't be doing anything with shproj then... same difference I suppose